# how can i find specific strings in string lines using regular expression in JAVA?

Tags: java, regex

I have three string lines here.

---

> line 1 :
>   56,C0348|23064,C0319|23182,C0127|1476,C0378|2004,C0260|3306,C0091|23179,C0525|
>
> line 2 : 8966,T4992|4446,T4992|4445,E|8965,E;T4992|8964,E;C0163|
>
> line 3 : 920,M128;C0323|

---

Now, my goal is to remove strings that have a form of "Tnumber|","Cnumber|" , "Mnumber|".

For example, in the first line, i want to delete "C0348|", "C0319|", "C0127|", "C0378|", "C0260|", "C0091|", "C0525|

In the second line , T4992|, T4992, T4992|, C0163|

In the third line, M128; C0323|

How can i remove those strings from each string line?

I think i need to use regular expression, right? 
but, i still can not solve this problem.

Could you please help me?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: ooppps sorry. the expected output will be "56,23064,23182,1476,2004,3306,23179, for the first line.

Comment: "8966,4446,4445,E|8965,E,;|8964,E;" for the second line.

Comment: 920, for the last line.

Comment: Rather go for a "proper" Java parser: Split the Strings on every separator (,) and then you can apply a regular expression.

Comment: thanks, do you know why these patterns do not work? "T[0-9]+|" "C[0-9]+|" "M[0-9]+|"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regular expression, like this

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    private static final String REGEX = "(T|M|C)\\d+(;|\\|)?";
    private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);

    public static String filterer(String inputString) {
        String result = "";
        for(String s : p.split(inputString)) {
            result += s;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(filterer("56,C0348|23064,C0319|23182,C0127|1476,C0378|2004,C0260|3306,C0091|23179,C0525|"));
        System.out.println(filterer("8966,T4992|4446,T4992|4445,E|8965,E;T4992|8964,E;C0163|"));
        System.out.println(filterer("920,M128;C0323|"));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
56,23064,23182,1476,2004,3306,23179,
8966,4446,4445,E|8965,E;8964,E;
920,
```

[RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hH0cZ3)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/1jTGZpQ7I6IpT-lN)

Of course, instead of having capture groups, we can use character classes like this

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Exz7B0lhC_wqcO6R)

Answer (score 1):

You may try a regexr of `[TCM]\d+[\|;]`, http://regexr.com/v1?38ls3. And as java source:

```
String reg= "[TCM]\\d+[\\|;]";
String line = "56,C0348|23064,C0319|23182,C0127|1476,C0378|2004,C0260|3306,C0091|23179,C0525|";
line = line.replaceAll(reg, "");
System.out.println(line);
line = "8966,T4992|4446,T4992|4445,E|8965,E;T4992|8964,E;C0163|";
line = line.replaceAll(reg, "");
System.out.println(line);
line = "920,M128;C0323|";
line = line.replaceAll(reg, "");
System.out.println(line);
```

output:

```
56,23064,23182,1476,2004,3306,23179,
8966,4446,4445,E|8965,E;8964,E;
920,
```

Comment: @user3149929 In the third line, "M128;" should be deleted? But you said the rule is "Mnumber|", so the rule should be "Mnumber;"?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. So, expression would be [TCM]\\d+(;|\\|)?. right?

Comment: `?` means "Zero or one", so if "\" or ";" must appears once, it should be "[TCM]\\d+[\\|;]". I've edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

as these are comma delimitered values you can split them as

```
String arr[] = line.split (",");

// iterate over them
int index = arr[0].indexOf ("|");
if (index != -1) {

   // do substring
}
```